# Verb for anfitrión

Tags: uso-de-palabras, verbos, sustantivos

What is the proper verb for "being an anfitrión", i.e. to receive guests, to host somebody, to be a host? I didn't find direct cognate word. Is there?

[Wordreference](http://www.wordreference.com/es/translation.asp?tranword=host) gives following two words in that sense: *alojar* and *hospedar*. *Hospedar* seems most relevant for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Hospedar* and *alojar* both refer to being a host in the sense of receiving guests/visitors and/or giving them lodging/accomodation. Neither of them refer to being a host in the much broader sense that *host* has in English, but *hospedar* is much closer, since *alojar* just means "to provide a place" (also *dar/proveer/brindar alojamiento*).

In any case *hospedar* and *anfitrión* are not as directly related (semantically) as *host* (the verb) and *host* (the noun) are in English. You might refer to Russia as the *anfitrión* (*anfitriona*?) of the 2018 FIFA World Cup, but you wouldn't say *«Rusia hospedará la Copa Mundial de la FIFA»*. In such cases you're better off just using the noun.

In other contexts *hospedar* is perfectly OK, but it's most natural to use it when there's a personal relationship between the host and the guests: it sounds a bit weird to say

> *El hotel me hospedó durante dos semanas.*

but you would naturally say

> *Mis amigos me hospedaron durante dos semanas.*

(For the former, you would say rather *«Me hospedé en el hotel durante dos semanas»*, with *hospedar* in the pronominal or pseudo-reflexive form. The latter would work as well as *«Me hospedé en lo de unos amigos durante dos semanas»*.)

You would likewise say:

> *Mis amigos fueron muy buenos anfitriones.*

but not

> *El hotel fue un muy buen anfitrión.*

Etymologically *host* and *hospedar* are cognates; *host* comes to English via French (it has the same root as *hospital[ity]*), and the corresponding Proto-Indoeuropean root ([**ghos-ti*](https://www.etymonline.com/word/*ghos-ti-)) is the source of English *guest*.

Comment: So, unlike *hospedar*, *alojar* can easily be used with hotel?

Comment: It's less personal and more businesslike, so yes. But generally also in the pseudo-reflexive form: *«Me alojé en un hotel»*.